# How to convert RDD[(String, String)] into RDD[Array[String]]?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to append filename to each record in the file. I thought if the RDD is Array it would have been easy for me to do it.

Some help with converting RDD type or solving this problem would be much appreciated!

In (String, String) type

```
scala> myRDD.first()(1)    
scala><console>:24: error: (String, String) does not take parametersmyRDD.first()(1)
```

In Array(string)

```
scala> myRDD.first()(1)    
scala> res1: String = abcdefgh
```

My function:

```
def appendKeyToValue(x: Array[Array[String]){
    for (i<-0 to (x.length - 1)) {
        var key = x(i)(0)
        val pattern = new Regex("\\.")
        val key2 = pattern replaceAllIn(key1,"|")
        var tempvalue = x(i)(1)
        val finalval = tempvalue.split("\n")
        for (ab <-0 to (finalval.length -1)){
            val result = (I am trying to append filename to each record in the filekey2+"|"+finalval(ab))
            }  
        }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have a `RDD[(String, String)]`, you can access the first tuple field of the first tuple by calling

```
val firstTupleField: String = myRDD.first()._1
```

If you want to convert a `RDD[(String, String)]` into a `RDD[Array[String]]` you can do the following

```
val arrayRDD: RDD[Array[String]] = myRDD.map(x => Array(x._1, x._2))
```

You may also employ a partial function to destructure the tuples:

```
val arrayRDD: RDD[Array[String]] = myRDD.map { case (a,b) => Array(a, b) }
```

Comment: Both answers provides solution to my query. Cheers!

Comment: Glad that I could help :-)