# How to determine original s3 input filenames from a pyspark rdd or partition

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using pyspark streaming to ETL input files from S3.

I need to be able to build an audit trail of all of the raw input files
on s3:// and where my parquet output ends up on hdfs://.

Given a dstream, rdd, or even a specific rdd partition, is it possible
to determine the original filename(s) of the input data in s3?

Currently the only way I know to do this is to take the
`rdd.toDebugString()` and attempt to parse it. However this feels really hacky and does not
work in some cases. For example, parsing the debug output does not work for batch mode imports that I
am also doing (using `sc.TextFile("s3://...foo/*")` style globs).

Does anyone have a sane way of determining the original filename(s)?

It seems some other spark users have had this question in the past, for
example:

http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Access-original-filename-in-a-map-function-tt2831.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had the same kind of problem and files were small enough so, we used `sc.wholeTextFiles("s3:...foo/*")` .

which creates RDD of `("<path/filename>","<content>")` and we appended the file name to content of files for usage.

[How to convert RDD[(String, String)] into RDD[Array[String]]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32583340/how-to-convert-rddstring-string-into-rddarraystring)

Comment: Excellent, this solves my problem for batch mode. However is there something like, hypothetically, `StreamingContext.wholeTextFileStream()` that allows me to get the source filenames from a rdd that comes from a `dstream`?